# Graph coloring: general question

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory, coloring

Assume we have a graph $ G=\langle V,E\rangle$ and there exists a coloring $ f\colon V \to A$  for a set $ A $ such that $ |A| = \alpha $.

> Is it true that for any set $ B $ such that $ |B|=\alpha $  exists a proper coloring $ g: V\to B $ ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As $A$ and $B$ have the same number of elements, there exists a bijection $b:A\to B$. Then just compose $f$ with $b$.

Comment: Understood, Waizman?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Indeed. Thank you.